# fireTableDataChanged() java

Tags: java, swing

Why does my model update the JTable view even if I do not call the fireTableDataChanged() ? Is this normal behaviour?

```
@Override
public void updateGUI(GUIUpdateEvent obj)
{
    System.out.println("updategui");
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            data[i][j] = obj.getBoard()[i][j].getCurrentPawnOnField().getChessIcon();
        }
    }
    //fireTableDataChanged();
}
```

Comment: If this code is outside of the TableModel class, then you should not be calling `fireTableDataChanged()` directly. This should only be called from within the model itself.

Comment: It is in subclass of AbstractTableModel class

Comment: Note that the answer to your question may have been generated by ChatGPT. Be wary of it.

Comment: @wydra__ *It is in subclass of AbstractTableModel class * - then your subclass must be invoking the appropriate fireXXX(...) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table model should always call the appropriate fire method (fireTableDataChanged, fireTableRowsUpdated, fireTableRowsInserted, etc.).  Doing so will tell the JTable to repaint the affected cells.

However, JTable (and all Swing components) may repaint themselves for other reasons.  Mouse events, including just moving the mouse over the table, may trigger repainting.  Moving or deiconifying the window may cause it repaint.  Scrolling a JTable may cause it to repaint.

While you have found a specific set of conditions where calling fireTableDataChanged was not needed, other users will not be so lucky.  If you call fireTableDataChanged, your table will update properly for everyone who runs your program.